# How to use filename to get back to workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am taking tabs out of a master workbook and creating separate workbooks with them. 
I then go back to the original master workbook and loop through all the tabs except my master tab.
I can put the master workbook file name and go back to it no problem but the master filename can change each time.
I need to take the filename from the master workbook and pass it into my VBA code to reference back to it. 
I think I'm close but not quite there

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim WB As Workbook
WB = GetThisWB2
Dim WSCount As Integer
WSCount = Worksheets.Count


Dim allsheets As Integer                
allsheets = WSCount                     
Do While allsheets > 1

Sheets(allsheets).Select
Sheets(allsheets).Move
''----Windows("FILENAME").Activate this works
WB.Activate

allsheets = allsheets - 1                  
Loop

End Sub

Function GetThisWB()

GetThisWB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
GetThisWB2 = ThisWorkbook.Name

End Function
```

Comment: You are just moving the sheets. Do you need to create separate workbook for each worksheet except the master sheet?

Comment: FYI: for all of the code residing within the master workbook, you can just use `ThisWorkbook` to reference it, and `ThisWorkbook.Name` to get it's name in a string. If you use `ThisWorkbook` in code, it always returns a reference to the workbook in which that code resides.

Comment: Misetella: Ha! So simple. Thank you very much

newguy: Yes, I need to save them in their own separate workbooks once they are split out. That's next to tackle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have described I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim wK as worksheet

For each wK in thisworkbook.Worksheets
  if wK.Name <> "Master" then

      wk.copy
      Activeworkbook.saveas thisworkbook.path & "\" & wk.name & ".xlsx"
      Activeworkbook.close true

  End if
Next wK

Msgbox "Process Completed"
End Sub
```